# ldap ssl connection parameters in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, ldap, openldap

I am trying to connect to ldaps server through through ldap_start_tls_s but i am continuously getting error -12(LDAP_INAPPROPRIATE_MATCHING).
Below is my code

```
const char*ldapServer=[@"ldaps://xx.xxx.xxx.xx" UTF8String];
LDAP        *ld;
int        rc;

/* Open LDAP Connection */

if( ldap_initialize( &ld, ldapServer ) )

{
    perror( "ldap_initialize" );

}

NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"server"

                                                     ofType:@"pem"];

NSString *newDir = [filePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/server.pem" withString:@""];

int version =  LDAP_VERSION3;

ldap_set_option(ld, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, &version);

//    ldap_set_option(ld, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CACERTFILE, [filePath UTF8String]);

//    ldap_set_option(ld, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CERTFILE,NULL);

//    ldap_set_option(ld, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_KEYFILE, NULL);

//    ldap_set_option(ld,LDAP_OPT_SSPI_FLAGS,0);

ldap_set_option(ld,LDAP_TIMELIMIT_EXCEEDED,[@"3000" UTF8String]);

ldap_set_option(ld,LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,0);

ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CTX, NULL);

ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CACERTDIR,[newDir UTF8String]);

rc = ldap_start_tls_s(ld, NULL, NULL);

if( rc != LDAP_SUCCESS )

{
    printf("start tls failed.\n");
}
```

I am stuck with this can any one help me to sort this out. Thanks in advance..

Comment: LDAP_INAPPROPRIATE_MATCHING-This result code indicates that an extensible match filter in a search request contained a matching rule that does not apply to the specified attribute type. I can not see what this has to do with startTLS. Can you try the same connection with startTLS?

Comment: Before Binding with this methods  ldap_sasl_bind_s(ld, bind_dn, LDAP_SASL_SIMPLE, &cred, NULL, NULL, NULL); i am trying to check weather the connection is established or not.